# Objective C : Expected Body of Lambda expression

Tags: objective-c

I am working on a small xcode project (my first project) using objective C and am trying to display a variable onto my label in the UI. I have declared the label onto the header file by "ctrl + connecting" it and creating a weak outlet connection but when I try to assign the text value of the label to my variable I get an error saying `Expected body of lambda expression`

Here is the snippet of the code that throws this error. I essentially want to assign the the variable `words` as the text for my label:

```
- (void)speak:(NSString *)words {
     NSLog(@"%@", words);
    labelForCategory.text = [words];
}
```

Any suggestions on how to navigate through this will be very helpful. The error is shown on the line `labelForCategory.text = [words];`

Comment: remove the `[ ]` surrounding `words` (a quick google search for `Expected body of lambda expression` would have given you the answer)

Comment: Curious, why did you add the `[ ]` around `words`?

Comment: Thank you, the error gets taken care of when I remove the [], however the label does not appear on the UI when run. I have it declared in the header file and then I call the label in this function. Is there a step I am? Does the label need to be initialized/called before setting its text like I have done above? Sorry I am new to this and have not had much luck "google-ing" this issue

Comment: I am guessing that you missed adding the view to the parent view's subviews? 
`[parentView addSubview:label];`
Also have you set the frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Words is a NSString object so remove [] as

```
- (void)speak:(NSString *)words {
 NSLog(@"%@", words);
labelForCategory.text = words;
 }
```